# Caml query on contents of a file

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, caml-query

I have a document library which contains metadata and a file (The file is .msg). I was wondering if it is possible to create a Caml-Query to query on the contents of the .msg? (Something as below?)

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name='?'/><Value Type='?'>Some text to check contents</Value>
            </Contains
        </Where>
     </Query>
 </View>
```